# Why 又 is used there instead of 再?

Tags: word-choice

In this dialogue:

> A: 现在恢复得怎么样了？
>   B: 没问题了，又可以爬山了。

Why is 又 used there and not 再?

As far as I know (I might be wrong), both 再 and 又 are used for describing recurring actions, but 又 refers to actions that took place in the past and 再 refers to future actions. So in the example, 可以爬山 (*I can climb mountains*) seems a future event (needs to go to a mountain first).

Comment: have you seen how the answers disagree? did you simply choose the one with the most upvotes?

Comment: @magnetar, point taken. My mistake was rushing to select it.

Comment: Good question. I make no mistake as to when to use which but I cannot explain. Makes me wonder how the brain works.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here, "又" means: "I **am able to** climb mountains **again**".

It is not a past or future event. "又可以" here is to show ability.

It implies, "I **was able to** climb mountains before the (illness), and I've now recovered, and I **am able to** climb mountains **again**".

Comment: +1 if i understand you right, the nuance here is that 又 is adding emphasis, right?

Comment: Now that you mentioned it, I think it can be treated as adding emphasis.

Answer (score 7):

In my opinion,

- 再 foresees the future, as  in 再见.
- 又 emphasis 'once more', as in "又可以爬山了"

Comment: +1 that's the way it feels to me. i am not a native speaker though. but in classical it seems to have this meaning, as in 玄之又玄

Answer (score 2):

This 又 "yòu" is more like "also" in this example. "I'm all right now, and I can climb mountains, too."

Probably most similar to the "yòu... yòu..."  (both...and...) pattern.

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with "also".

Comment: -1 this answer seems to disagree with the consensus by the native speakers on here.

Comment: Answers given to learners of Chinese are useful when they allow the learner to make the right word choice. I think that thinking of this structure in this way does that.

Answer (score 2):

又 has the connotation of "there you go again." That is, of repeating a **past** action in the present.

再 is anticipatory: That is, planning to repeat a present action in the **future.** 再见, used for "good-bye," literally means "see you AGAIN," (soon). It is the equivalent of the French au revoir or the German auf Wiedersehen.

Answer (score 2):

Your question： Why is 又 used there and not 再 in the above sentence?

First, you need to know the difference of 再 and 又.

1) 再 means“again”，can be used to repeat the same action in the future  which haven’t happened yet; 
2) 又 means “again” too, but is used for the past to emphasize the event had already happened.

For example:

服务员，再来一杯啤酒。
When I finished a cup of beer, I want to order one more, I can say “Waiter, one more, please.” So here I should use “再”。

老师，可以再说一次吗？
The teacher had asked me a question, but she spoke very fast and I didn’t get it, here I can say “Teacher, could you please say it again?” The teacher haven’t said it again yet, So here is “再”。

你怎么又迟到了？
Yesterday I was late, my boss was a little bit angry, and today I was late again, he asked me “Why did you late again?” I was late, this event had happened this morning, so here we should use “又”。

我这次又没通过考试。
Last time I didn’t pass the exam, and this time I failed again. I got my report and I knew I didn’t pass the exam either. So here we use “又”。

So you need to use "又" in this dialogue.

A: 现在恢复得怎么样了？

B: 没问题了，又可以爬山了。

If you want to know more about [how to use "再" and "又"？](http://www.hanbridgemandarin.com/course/demo/zai-and-you)Please check the free video.